# Mongodb: is replacing an array with a new version more efficient than adding elements to it?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a single `/update-user` endpoint on my server that triggers an `updateUser` query on mongo.

Basically, I retrieve the user id thanks to the cookie, and inject the received form, that can comprise any kind of key allowed in the User model, in the mongo query.

It looks like:

```js
const form = {
  friends: [{id: "1", name: "paul", thumbnail: "www.imglink.com"},
            {id: "2", name: "joe", thumbnail: "www.imglink2.com"}],
  locale: "en",
  age: 77
}

function updateUser(form, _id){
  const query = JSON.stringify(form)
  return UserDB.findOneAndUpdate( { _id }, { $set: query })
}
```

So each time, I erase the necessary data and replace it by a brand new one. Sometimes, this data can be an array of 50 objects (let's say I've removed two persons in a 36 friends array as described above).

It is very convenient, because I can abstract all the logic both in the front and back with a single update function. However, is this a pure heresy from a performance point of view? Should I rather use 10 endpoints to update each part of the form?

The form is dynamic, I never know what is going to be inside, except that it belongs to the User model, this is why I've used this strategy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From MongoDB's point of view, it doesn't matter much. MongoDB is a journalled database (particularly with the WiredTiger storage engine), and it probably (re)writes a large part of the document on update. It might make a minor difference under very heavy loads when replicating the `oplog` between primary and replicas, but if you have performance constraints like these, you'll know. If in doubt, benchmark and monitor your production system - don't over-optimize.

Focus on what's best for the business domain. Is your application collaborative? Do multiple users edit the same documents at the same time? What happens when they overwrite one another's changes? Are the JSONs that the client sends to the back-end large, or do they not clog up the network? These are the most important questions you should ask, and performance should only be optimized once you have the UX, the interaction model and the concurrency issues nailed.

Comment: Thanks for your complete answer. No, it's only a single user update. The ux to update a profile is a form divided into small blocks. Each blocks allows the user to edit a part of his profile, and save it independently. So there can be up to 7 different updates during a "update profile" session. The largest json could be an array of 50 objects, each containing 3 keys. I don't know if it's too much. I send it in the body of the request, no form data.